# Removing words from a String (while using specific methods)

Tags: java

I want to remove all instances of 1 specific word ("STOP") from a given String.
I need to accomplish this by first splitting the String

This is what I've got so far:

```
public static String telegram(String sentence)
    {
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if(words[i].equals("STOP"))
            {
                ...
            }
        }

    }
```

How do I go about removing the words?
I've tried using the for loop and making the Array element with the word null, but I'm not sure if that'll work.

I need to use the methods append(String) and toString() and I'm not sure how to use these.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are some examples of inputs this method would receive?

Comment: HINT HINT HINT --> Use a `StringBuilder`. It has append and toString()

Answer (score 3):

if you have to do this with the split method you would want something like this.

```
public static String telegram(String sentence)
{
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if(!words[i].equals("STOP"))
        {
            result.append(words[i]);
            result.append(" ");
        }
    }
  return result.toString();

}
```

if you dont have to use slip i would suggest using the replace all method, make your code simpler.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question :)

Comment: This works, but it removes all the spaces. 
Here's an input/output example: 
Input: *"A stopsign is an octogonal sign with STOP on it. STOP You should always stop for a stopsign. STOP "*
Output: **"A stopsign is an octogonal sign with on it. You should always stop for a stopsign. "**

Comment: a yes, forgot about those littler buggers.. i'll make an edit

Comment: @TrickBoss You can use `result.append(words[i]).appent(" ");` although you should do it only for `i < words.length - 1` to not add space after last word.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is using append and toString you can do this

```
            public static String telegram(String sentence) {
                String[] words = sentence.split("STOP");
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    builder.append(words[i]);
                }
                return builder.toString();

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You are splitting on `"STOP"` which is approach I also was going to suggest since there is no info about what String we should use in split. I guess it is +1 for you but I would also add one space after `"STOP "` assuming that [OP example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690390/removing-words-from-a-string-while-using-specific-methods#comment29247507_19690463) is correct.

Comment: The requirement didn't say anything about spaces. Every example above is assuming the word STOP will have space before and after.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace it by 
`sentence = String.replaceAll("STOP","");`

EDIT: Sorry misunderstanding

Use **StringBuilder** as recommended

Comment: Read the post again. There has to be certain methods used!

Comment: I'd give you your -1 back but now it's basically a comment.

Comment: @alex2410 there is [delete] option under your answer. Feel free to use it. This way you will get back lost reputation and number of similar answers will decrease making this question more readable.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, technically, you can't remove words from a String. In Java, Strings are immutable. What you probably want to do then, is to create a new String exactly like the original except that the word "STOP" is removed.

<del>You can do this fairly easily by using `String.replaceAll` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)). In fact, the method could be this short:</del>

```
return sentence.replaceAll("STOP", "");
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had constraints on the methods you had to use.

You might want to take a look at StringBuilder. After splitting the String with the delimiter "STOP", you are left with an array of Strings that comprise the message with the stops removed. Then you can use `StringBuilder.append` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)) to create a StringBuilder representing the whole message again and then use the StringBuilder's `toString()` method to return the contents of the StringBuilder as a String.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. I corrected my post to use methods specified by the OP.